# Overlaying an image on camera preview on iOS using Phonegap

Tags: ios, camera, cordova

I am looking to create an app in which a semi transparent image is overlaid on the camera preview. I know their is no support for this in the native Phonegap camera api. I'm wondering if anyone who has some experience with writing Phonegap plugins can give me any advice on whether this would be possible with a plugin. I think I have seen that this technique is possible through native code so it seems to me that it would be possible to write a Phonegap plugin to access this functionality, I just don't have any experience with Phonegap plugins.

Comment: Im looking for the same thing... Have you ever found something?

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question but worth a look: http://libresoft.es/node/146. The source is available at the bottom and it's based on phonegap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know, it's a little bit too late but there is a way (iPad only). You can use the standard `org.apache.cordova.camera`-Plugin. But you have to tweak it a bit

First subclasse the `CDVCameraPicker` so you can toggle the overlay via cordova-api:

CDVCameraPicker+Overlay.h:

```
#import "CDVCamera.h"

@interface CDVCameraPicker (Overlay)
@property (nonatomic, strong) id showOverlay;
@end
```

CDVCameraPicker+Overlay.m:

```
#import "CDVCameraPicker+Overlay.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static void *overlayKey;

@implementation CDVCameraPicker (Overlay)
@dynamic showOverlay;

- (void) setShowOverlay:(id)showOverlay {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, overlayKey, showOverlay, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
- (id) showOverlay {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, overlayKey);
}
@end
```

Then add these lines to the CDVCamera.m right after checking the ImagePickerSourceType (Line 132)

```
    if ([cameraPicker.showOverlay intValue] == 1) {
        UIImageView *overlay = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
        overlay.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        overlay.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"overlay.png"];
    }
```

Don't forget to import your subclassed CameraPicker in the CDVCamera.m
`#import "CDVCameraPicker+Overlay.h"`

No you have to edit the `Camera.js`-File 
Add this line underneath the other options

```
var showOverlay = getValue(options.showOverlay, false);
```

Then add the `var` to the `args`-Array at last index. And that's it. Now you can toggle your overlay like this:

```
       navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 40,
                        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                        correctOrientation: true,
                        saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
                        showOverlay: false
                    });
```

Comment: This is a bit of an old one and from a long done project (or abandoned can't remember) but I wanted to take the time to thank you for this in depth answer. I may need this again in the future and I am sure it will come in handy!

Comment: @tmartineau I tried this, but it didn't work. Do you know if this still works with newest version of Cordova? The only way I can get the overlay image to appear is in the  ` if (cameraPicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) `  around line 685 in the CDVCamera.m. I use this line of code `UIImageView *overlayImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]];
        overlayImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
        cameraPicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayImage;`  The problem is it takes 10 seconds to load or not at all.

Comment: @tmartineau If you have a sample project, I'd love to see it.

Comment: @paul I never got to try this out. As I said in my comment the original question was years ago and from a long dead project. matthisb might be able to give you some insight since this was his answer. Sorry I could not be of more help at the moment.

Comment: @tmartineau Sorry about that. I meant to address matthisb. I did figure it out though. I'll post the code here as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the accepted answer, but unfortunately did not work for me.

Instead I found a much simpler solution. In the `CDVCamera.m`:

```
  + (instancetype) createFromPictureOptions(CDVPictureOptions*)pictureOptions;{

      CDVCameraPicker* cameraPicker = [[CDVCameraPicker alloc] init];
      cameraPicker.pictureOptions = pictureOptions;
      cameraPicker.sourceType = pictureOptions.sourceType;
      cameraPicker.allowsEditing = pictureOptions.allowsEditing;

if (cameraPicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
    // More code...

         // Here is where you place your overlay.
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImageView *overlayImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
            overlayImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
            [cameraPicker.cameraOverlayView addSubview:overlayImage];
            [cameraPicker setCameraOverlayView:overlayImage];
     });

   //  Code left out for brevity
   }
}
```

It's important to perform the overlay using Grand Central Dispatch.