# Camera overlay plugin for Phonegap

Tags: cordova, camera

what I want to accomplish is to overlay a html canvas on camera live feed. Is it possible to create a new camera launcher plugin that provides a transparent background? Any other ideas?

Comment: This same question is being asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274071/overlaying-an-image-on-camera-preview-on-ios-using-phonegap?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overlaying an image on camera preview on iOS using Phonegap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274071/overlaying-an-image-on-camera-preview-on-ios-using-phonegap)